# Creating html table dynamically from xml response?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

I have a xml file and I am trying to read that file using Angular.js. This is the code of angular:

```
 <script>
    var app = angular.module('httpApp', []);
    app.controller('httpController', function ($scope, $http) {
        $http.get("abc.xml",
            {
                transformResponse: function (cnv) {
                    var x2js = new X2JS();
                    var aftCnv = x2js.xml_str2json(cnv);
                    return aftCnv;
                }
            }).then(function (response) {
                console.log(response.data); //It's working fine
            });
    });
</script>
```

Above console.data is working but further I am trying to get columns and data from the xml like this and that shows error. [Same two lines are working if I am trying to read json file but not in the case of XML.]

```
$scope.rowsdata = response.data; //all the data - NO ERROR TILL HERE
$scope.column = Object.keys($scope.rowsdata[0]); //all the columns-ERROR STATEMENT - LINE NO 25 THAT SHOWS ERROR
```

After getting all the columns and data I will make a html table in angular js but Below is the error I am getting:

[image]

Output of console.log($scope.rowsdata) is

[image]

Thanks for the help.

Comment: What is the output of `$scope.rowsdata`? Share the output of `console.log($scope.rowsdata)`

Comment: Looks like $scope.rowsdata[0] is empty, so Object.keys is trying to find the keys of an empty array.

You should probably throw in a condition to check whether or not you've gotten a response?

Comment: @Satpal added the output.

Comment: Use `$scope.rowsdata.CATALOG.CD[0]`

Comment: @Satpal It is giving me data of only first row. Is there any way to get all the data in data.

Comment: Yep, Just use `$scope.columnData = $scope.rowsdata.CATALOG.CD`